# Чат-бот вк. Ошибка: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Ошибка вылетает когда я пишу сообщение в беседу с ботом. Подходящего решения в интернете не нашел.
Код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\vk_bot\vk.py", line 23, in <module>
    msg = event.object.message['text'].lower
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Код самого бота:

```
import vk_api, random
from random import randrange
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from toks import main_token
from legs import legs

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 999999999)

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

#def send_photo(id, ph_url):
 #   vk.messages.send(chat_id=id, attachment=ph_url, random_id=0)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        if event.from_chat:

            id = event.chat_id
            msg = event.object.message['text'].lower


            if msg == 'txt':
                sender(id, 'txt')
                #i = random.choice(legs)
                #random_index = randrange(len(legs))
                #send_photo(id, i)
                #print('выполнено')
            else:
                sender(id, 'txt')
```

Comment: А зачем вы добавляете к `event` функцию `object`? И `lower` надо писать так `lower()` - это функция.

Comment: походу когда переписывал ее, забыл добавить, но так тоже не работает

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `object`, то есть напишите так: `msg = event.text.lower()`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Странно, ну, попробуйте тогда так `event.object['text']`